# Writing to Text file using JS only

Tags: javascript, text

I need to write to a text file using JavaScript. I have a machine I need to run some HTML file on and it uses JS to manipulate content. I want to log the changes the user makes in a text file, and the computer does not have and *will never have* any server-side scripting language. So I just wanna know how to append text to a txt file using JS only. Alternatively, running a batch script upon JS call that will do the work itself, is a good equivalent, but I'm sure it's the same level of difficulty...

The script will work on an IE only machine, but I need to be able to test it on other browsers as well... So I'm not sure how and if ActiveX works on Chrome for example, but if it doesn't, I need another solution... Help please! :)

Comment: Good luck... I doubt it's gonna work as well as you want.

Comment: Why do you want to manipulate a text file? Do you need an actual .txt, or are you just looking for persistant client-side storage?

Comment: The web app I'm making is a listing changer for some company. The limitation on that computer is that no software can be installed, including a server... and I need to create an automated log for the listing changes. I literally need just to write to a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the solution I was looking for, but I ended up using cookies, which limits the amount of data I can hold to very little, but beats nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While there's some promise with the new [File](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) API, you'll probably need to go with a server-sided language for reliable file-writing.

Some possible alternatives are to 'write' the changes to the `localStorage`, or perhaps to create a `URI` download. There's plenty of tutorials online for setting these up. Good luck!

Comment: As the question states, I'm limited to browser technology only. No server client-scripting, this computer can't have a server installed an has no internet access even. I need to paste my HTML/JS files and be able to create and append a text file so that it would log things relevant to the script.

Comment: As for localStorage, this machine runs IE6 with no possibility to upgrade/change... So I'm not capable of using HTML5